# using here script I/O redirection with su command

Tags: su

here is my script. I want to login with another user and do `ls -lih`:

```
#!/bin/bash

su - testuser <<- _EOF_
    123456 #password
    _EOF_

ls -lih
```

here is the output when i ran script:

```
./script.sh
-bash: line 1: 123456: command not found
total 127M
 262210 drwxr-xr-x.  9 mazimi mazimi 156K Feb 14 19:05 Desktop
 262211 drwxr-xr-x.  2 mazimi mazimi  36K Feb 14 18:26 Downloads
 278106 -rw-r--r--   1 mazimi mazimi  64K Feb 14 22:30 ems.cfg
 ... # list of files
```

It does `ls -lih` in my home directory not `testuser`? How should I fix it?

Comment: So the `su` actually works?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are several problems with your code.

1. `su` reads the password from `/dev/tty`, not from `stdin`, so you can't redirect the password like this.  In fact, what `su` does by default is start a shell as the target user, so if you run this as `root`:

   ```
   su - testuser <<- _EOF_
   123456 #password
   _EOF_
   ```

   The `su` will succeed (root doesn't need a password to do this), but the `123456` will get passed as input to the user's shell, which is why when you run your script you see:

   ```
   -bash: line 1: 123456: command not found
   ```

   If you want to do this as a non-root user, you should probably follow bahamt's advice and use `sudo`, which can be configured to offer password-free access to specific commands as a different user.
2. Even if the `su` works, it spawns a new process.  The `su` command has exited (and returned to the original account) before the `ls` command executes.  So what you really want is:

   ```
   su - testuser <<EOF
   ls -lih
   EOF
   ```

Comment: You could use something like `script` (the utility called script, not write a script), to wrap around `su`, but thats a hack. A really ugly hack. Agree with sudo

Answer (score 1):

I think you'll find that you can't fix it.  I think that `su` reads `/dev/tty` for the password, and I believe you can't really redirect to that magic device file.

If you're using linux, you can verify what `su` reads for the password with `strace`.

Answer (score 1):

What you actually want to use is `sudo`.

You might want to start [here](http://www.linuxhomenetworking.com/wiki/index.php/Quick_HOWTO_%3a_Ch09_%3a_Linux_Users_and_Sudo#Using_sudo).