# Logging in with 'su' without entering a password

Tags: terminal, password, su

How can I log in with the `su` command in one line in the terminal? I know that the `sudo` command can do that:

```
echo [password] | sudo -S [command]
```

But when I try to imply it in the `su` command :

```
echo [password] | su [username]
```

I get an error:

```
standard in must be tty
```

I don't have access to the `sudo` account (so I can't access and edit the `sudoers` file).

**I know that the right syntax is basically:**

```
su [username]
```

**What I want to do is to add a `su` command to aliases without being needed to enter password every time**

Comment: you can't, the error message is pretty clear; see also larsks' [answer here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/31675)

Comment: The synatax is incorrect for su

Comment: You can use `expect` to solve your problem, but you won't be able to do it in just one line.

Comment: If you have superuser rights anyway just give you sudo rights. Otherwise the fastest possible way to get a root shell via `su` is this: `su --login`, but you need to interactively enter the root password.

Comment: `alias stupidsu='sudo -i -u '` - the subtle ways this will bite you in the bum would take a VERY long time to explain. Why don't you just use a properly configured sudo (even `sudo su`)

Answer (score 1):

> Asked 6 years, 2 months ago

> **How can I** log in with the **su** command in one line in the terminal?

This is for using **sudo** with not getting prompted for a password every time :

edit the `/etc/sudoers` file via  `visudo`  or  `sudo visudo`

in RHEL/CentOS 7 at least, down at the bottom of the `/etc/sudoers` file you will see the COMMANDS section.  Specifically this:

```
## Allows people in group wheel to run all commands
%wheel  ALL=(ALL)   ALL

## Same thing without a password
# %wheel    ALL=(ALL)   NOPASSWD: ALL
```

by default... for RHEL/CentOS I can't speak for other linux distro's on how they may make use of this... simply comment out the first with `#` and put into effect the line having the `NOPASSWD: ALL` syntax.  Or enter this syntax.

The `%wheel` means those accounts in the *wheel* group as defined in `/etc/group`.  You can add a line and make it `%users` for example to allow any account in the *users* group this no password functionality, if you use the *users* group (with gid 100) in that manner.

For the **How can I** of being just you, the `%wheel` syntax with the `%` means *wheel* is a group.  To specify a specific user account, just remove the `%` and use a user account in place of the group name.  For example:

```
## Allow root to run any commands anywhere
root    ALL=(ALL)       ALL
```

simply do this if your user account name is *abc123*

```
abc123  ALL=(ALL)   NOPASSWD: ALL
```

and best to put this at the bottom of the file so that if said user account is also part of wheel group and that is in effect above that statement doesn't override and undo this if you put this *user* statement at the top of the file.

I do not know how to undo the password prompt of using **su** in the above manner but

what you can do is `sudo su <username>` and not get prompted for password, along with doing `sudo su` and su'ing to the root account without a password.

What I've described is the best way I know on how to gain no password prompting functionality while maintaining decent security at the same time... the `/etc/sudoers` file is the security focal point here.

The file permissions of `/etc/sudoers` should be `root` for both owner and group with `-r--r-----` permissions or 440.

**note:** using `abc123  ALL=(ALL)   NOPASSWD: ALL` will allow that user account to do a `sudo su` and switch to the root account without being prompted for the root account's password.

Answer (score 0):

The correct answer is:
**THIS IS DANGEROUS ! DO NOT DO THIS ! IT COMPLETELY BREAKS YOUR SECURITY !!!**

But...
If you don't care about security you can do it like this:

- Create a file `main.c` with the contents:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main() {
  setuid(0);
  system("/bin/bash"); //you can replace bash by another shell if wanted
  return 0;
}
```

- Compile this code and transform it into a suid shell with:

```
gcc main.c -o mysuidshell
sudo chown root mysuidshell && sudo chmod u+s mysuidshell
```

You can now create the alias that you mentinoed in the comment on LXGA's answer:

`alias switch="/path/to/mysuidshell"`.

Although it's still terrible idea security-wise, you also have the extremely tiny advantage that your password is not somewhere visible in cleartext.

Depending on what you want to do you can change the code so that it can change to other users than root, run different shells, ...

But you will be basically re-inventing the wheel (`su` and `sudo`) but less secure.

Answer (score 0):

This is exactly what Expect was designed for.  It was written originally for Tcl/Tk, but I'm not terribly *au fait* with that language, so here it is in Python:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import os,sys,pexpect

child = pexpect.spawn("sudo head /etc/shadow")

# Give it a list of expected responses (only one here)    
Result = child.expect([" password for"])

# Did we find the zeroth answer in our list?
if Result==0:
    # Yes, then send the password
    child.sendline('<your password>')
    # Output its response
    print(child.read())
else:
    print("Didn't get expected response")
```

You'll have to edit it to suit your purpose, hopefully that's enough to get you started.

Answer (score 0):

#### tl;dr:

As root,

1. In `/etc/pam.d/su`, add the line: `auth sufficient pam_wheel.so trust`    before the other lines.
2. Execute `getent group wheel || groupadd wheel`
3. Execute `usermod -aG wheel joeuser` (for a user named `joeuser`)

### Longer explanation

On Unix systems, it is customary to use the `wheel` group to grant users administrator/root privileges; but - this the privilege escalation capability is not enabled by default. On modern Linux systems (last 15 years at least and probably well before), that can be done by adding a line to the PAM  [configuration files](https://linux.die.net/man/5/pam.d) under `/etc/pam.d/` - and specifically, to the `su` file. The line says: "If the user is in the wheel group, this suffices as authentication".

Of course, you actually need to be put in that wheel group, hence the instructions on creating the group if it doesn't exist (which is often, as Linux distros don't typically create it on installation), then making the addition.

that's it. Joe User can now run `su` without providing a password.

Notes:

- This is an older mechanism than sudo and doesn't rely on it.
- See this question about creation of groups: [Short, simple command to create a group if it doesn't already exist?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/145348/34868)

about the command for creating the group.